# How to jump between lines in for loop in python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a file of sequence information, so the file will be structured like this,

```
[SEQUENCE ID]
atgctagctagatcga
[SEQUENCE ID]
agatcgatggctagatc
```

What I've been doing is comparing between files to see what sequences IDs are shared, which is simple enough, but now I want to pull out the actual sequence associated with the ID. The files I'm using are huge (10 GB+) so using a dictionary or anything that would involve reading all the lines into the system memory is out.

Basically what the code is intended to do is if the sequence ID from file 1 isn't found in file 2, then return the line after the sequence ID from file 1. Any tips?

Comment: Are the two files sorted by sequence-id?  If so, then lookups in file could maybe be done in a binary search fashion.

Comment: are the files sorted in order of sequence id?

Comment: Dump the files into a DBMS then `join` them ?

Comment: Can you read the [SEQUNECE ID's] of both files into memory? It might be possible to do what you are asking without a database them - oterhwise, check my answer.

Comment: Can't read the sequence ID's of both files into memory, too much memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you only need line N and line N+1? In this case read the file in chunks of two lines. Then you always have access to both the sequence ID and the sequence.

```
from itertools import izip
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line1, line2 in izip(*(iter(f),) * 2):
        print line1, line2
```

Comment: I don  think this answer is usefull in anyform. While it helps with picking the correct data, that is nto the actual problem - rather, making eficient searchs in the huge ammoun of data is.

Comment: ah hm.. looks like the OP added the last paragraph after I posted this answer.

Comment: Hmm..IMO, the last paragraph is the _actual_ question.

Comment: No actually picking out the correct data is the problem. I've accepted the fact that dealing with files of this size is just an absolute balls :(

Comment: So you really should check the options of importing your dat ainto a database system. I've postedd anotehr answer in case the IDś of just one file fit in your memory.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you will have to use a third party Python library to keep one of the data sequences searchable in better than O(n).

If they are not sorted, you will have to sort at least one of the files. Think of it this way:
I get the sequence ID from file 1 - and to check if it is not present in file2, I'dhave to read all the file - much eless feasible than reading the file once.

Than - better than sorting, it would be usefull to have a data-structure that could hold the sorted data on disc in a way to provide for fast searchs, and still be able to grow - that woulf facilitate sorting as well,a s all you'd have to do in a first step would be reading the entries in file 2, and just inserting then into this growing-sorted disk-persisted data structure.

While certainly you could roll your own data-structure to do this, I'd suggest the ue of **[ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/)** - ZOPE's object oriented DATABSe, witha  btree folder, and have your "2 lines of data"  made into a minimal object for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the [SEQUENCE ID] s do fit in memory, and that the bulk of your data is actually on the sequence line (unlike the examples provided) - you have the option to parse a file (file2 in your question), and anotate not only te [SEQUENCE ID] - but the file postion for each such identifier. This approach would enable you to proceed without braking much of your current workflow (like, having to learn about a database)
:

```
def get_indexes(filename):
    with open(filename, "rt") as file:
        sequences = {}
        while True:
            position = file.tell()
            id = file.readline()
            if not id:
                break()
            sequences[id.strip()] = position
            # skip corresponding data line:
            file.readline()
    return sequences

def fetcher(filename1, filename2, sequences):
    with open(filename1, "rt") as file1, open(filename2, "rt" as file2):
        while True:
            id = file.readline()
            data = file.readline()
            if not id:
                break
            id = id.strip()
            if id in sequences:
                # postion file2 reading at the identifier:
                file2.seek(sequences[id])
                # throw away id:
                file2.readline()
                data = file.readline()

            yield id, data

if __name__== "__main__":
    sequences = getindexes("/data/file2")
    for id, data in fetcher("/data/file1", "/data/file2", sequences):
        print "%s\n%s"% (id, data)
```

Comment: The the sequences ID won't fit in memory either, theres hundreds of millions of them!

Comment: So - check my other answer  - it is past the tiem you move to a database product - either ZODB - which will allow you do treat each of your entries as a full Python object in a transparent way, or an SQL engine - whichi can do a nice job in this case as well.